# Splitting lines at certain lengths in ArcGIS ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, splitting

How to split lines at a certain length in the ArcGIS ModelBuilder using below the split tool from the Editor Toolbox?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use the Split tool from the Editor toolbar in ModelBuilder because it is not a geoprocessing tool.

However, there is an [How To: Split a line into specified distances with a remainder](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000017659) which tells you how to do it using two geoprocessing tools which can be used in ModelBuilder:

> A line can be split at specified distances with a remainder length
> using the [Generate Points Along Lines](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/generate-points-along-lines.htm) and [Split Line at Point](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/split-line-at-point.htm) tools.
> Using these tools, the remaining distance is less than the specified
> distance.
>
> Note: The Split Line at Point tool is only available in ArcGIS Desktop
> with an Advanced license.